# Receiving XML with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, xml, web-services, file-get-contents

I am new to this site and also new to web services.  I am trying to create a web service that sends an xml response back to a client request.  The problem I am having is when I execute the client request, the browser hangs and eventually comes back with a server time out error.  I have checked the PHP.INI settings to make sure allow_url_fopen is set to on.
I am hosting the website on an IBM i using Zend Server.
Thanks in advance for your help.

This is how I am trying to do it:

Server side:  This file is called XML3.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
header("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>";
echo '<posts>';
    echo '<post>';
    echo "<title>title1</title>";
    echo "<body>this is the body</body>";
    echo "<post_date>02/10/2012</post_date>";
    echo '</post>';
echo '</posts>';
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Client side:

```
<?php 
$xml = file_get_contents('http://corvetteamericadealers.com/dev1/Examples/XML3.php');
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
var_dump($sxe);
```

Comment: Do `new SimpleXMLElement($url, 0, true);`. And there is no need for the output buffering either.

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine for me. Just check.

```
<?php
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
{
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        $contents = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);

        if ($contents) return $contents;
            else return FALSE;
 }

$xmlString = curl_get_file_contents("http://corvetteamericadealers.com/dev1/Examples/XML3.php");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
var_dump($xml); 
?>
```

And this is my output.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) 
{ ["post"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (3) 
{ 
["title"]=> string(6) "title1" 
["body"]=> string(16) "this is the body" 
["post_date"]=> string(10) "02/10/2012" } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I must have something not set correctly in PHP INI because this code hangs as well.  I'll dig into PHP INI and see if there is something I need to change there.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing web service by parsing soap xml? Use some web service mechanism for generate classes from .wsdl file.

Comment: I was hoping to use a REST type web service